# how to do mixedsort to a dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: r, sorting, datatable

I need to sort the data frame by 4 different levels.
By level1 which is a mix of numbers and characters. result should be 0 to 100 and after that a to z.
by level 2 alphabetically
by level 3 + level 4 (combined together and then sorted from smallest to largest)
by level 5 this is a date.

```r
Treaty <- data.frame(
     Level.1 = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 41, 66, 87, 94, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
     Level.2 = c("P", "E", "P", "E", "P", "E", "P", "E", "P", "E", "P", "E", "P", "E"),
     Level.3 = c(0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 1000, 2000),
     Level.4 = c(9000, 10000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 1000, 2000),
     Level.5 = c(44689, 44570, 44620, 44805, 44720, 44624, 44749, 44745, 44810, 44813, 44683, 44561, 44601, 44626)
 )
```

I need all 5 columns to sorted just as we do in excel.
notice that vector Level.1 is alphanumeric, so order can not be used.
for the single column `mixedsort(Treaty$Level.1)`, this code works well.
But I need this entire dataframe to be sorted.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you expect the output to look like based on the example you've provided (and ideally code that you've already tried)?

Comment: Please provide some clarity: the [tag:datatable] tag is ambiguous. It seems unlikely to be the .NET library, nor does it appear to be the javascript library, so _this_ tag is not appropriate. If you mean the `data.table` R _package_, then please use [tag:data.table] instead. If none of those are true and it was applied because you are working with an R `data.frame`, then it is (still) not appropriate. Please edit your tags to reflect this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't super clear what you meant by "by level 3 + level 4 (combined together and then sorted from smallest to largest)" but you should be able to adapt something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
Treaty %>%
  arrange(order(stringr::str_order(Level.1, numeric = TRUE)),
          Level.2,
          Level.3,
          Level.4,
          as.Date(Level.5))
```

Here, I'm using `str_order()` as an alternative to `mixedsort()` but you could edit it to use that instead if you really want to.

Comment: Edit to add `library(dplyr)` and use {magrittr} pipe as well, so no dependence on R 4.1+ anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can anything be done if i wish to reverse the order for Level.2

Comment: You could replace `Level.2` with `desc(Level.2)` inside `arrange()` to sort in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `order` for this, taking an extra step to accommodate `Level.1`'s mixed use of integers and letters.

```r
Treaty[order(
  suppressWarnings(as.integer(Treaty$Level.1)), 
  match(Treaty$Level.1, letters),
  Treaty$Level.2, Treaty$Level.3, Treaty$Level.4, Treaty$Level.5),]
#    Level.1 Level.2 Level.3 Level.4 Level.5
# 4        1       E       0    2000   44805
# 1        1       P       0    9000   44689
# 3        1       P     500    1000   44620
# 2        3       E       0   10000   44570
# 5       41       P       0    3000   44720
# 6       66       E       0    4000   44624
# 7       87       P       0    5000   44749
# 8       94       E       0    6000   44745
# 9        a       P    7000    7000   44810
# 10       b       E    8000    8000   44813
# 11       c       P    9000    9000   44683
# 12       d       E   10000   10000   44561
# 13       e       P    1000    1000   44601
# 14       f       E    2000    2000   44626
```

- we handle mixed ints and letters in `Level.1` by first trying to convert to numbers; here, this will produce `c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 41L, 66L, 87L, 94L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)`, using the default `order(..., na.last=TRUE)`;
- by then sorting on `match(Level1, letters)`, which will produce `c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)` which continues to sort correctly;
- the rest of the levels are simple sorting